# ASP.NET Ajax Extensions 1.0 on server with framework 3.5?

Tags: .net-3.5, asp.net-ajax

Is it possible to install ASP.NET Ajax Extensions 1.0 for ASP.NET 2.0 on a web server that has the 3.5 framework installed? I have a project targeted for the 2.0 framework (cannot run 3.5), and I need it to run basic ASP.NET Ajax on a server that has the 3.5 framework installed.

I tried installing Ajax Extensions 1.0 but it claimed they were already installed and asked me to repair and I chickened out of it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

The GAC supports side-by-side versioning of dlls, so multiple versions of System.Web.Extensions.dll can exist and run together peacefully.

If you're not doing development on the web server, to install ASP.NET Ajax Extensions 1.0 for ASP.NET 2.0, all you need to do is copy the System.Web.Extensions.dll (Version=1.0.61025.0) into the GAC.

(In your situation, you might have to install the .msi on a different server to get the System.Web.Extensions.dll out in the first place)

Make sure in the application to use the fully qualified assembly name when referencing ASP.NET Ajax Extensions 1.0 for ASP.NET 2.0.  You'll need to check your [web.config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907639.aspx) carefully to make sure all System.Web.Extensions references point to the right version.  Anyways, The fully qualified assembly name will be:

```
System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
```

So, I'm not sure why the installer didn't work for you, but since you don't need to actually execute the .msi on every machine you want to use it on (only if you need access to the source code), you should be ok with just the dll in the GAC.